# Proof that $-(-x) = x$ using just the field axioms

Tags: field-theory, solution-verification

This is my attempt based on some stuff I have been seeing around:

Let $y = -x$, then $-y = -(-x)$.

Now, lets sum $y + x = (-x) + x = 0$, then we have $y + x = 0$. If we had the additive inverse of $x$, i.e $-x$, to both sides, we obtain:

$$y + x + (-x) = 0 + (-x) \\ y + 0 = 0 + (-x) \\ y = -x\\ -y = x \\ -(-x) = x$$.

Is this proof correct just using the field axioms? I think that the key point is finding that $y = -x$.

Comment: Since $x+(-x)=0=(-x)+x$, we see *by definition* that $-x$ is the opposite element of $x$, which amounts to saying that $x=-(-x)$.

Comment: please state field axiom

Answer (score 3):

The statement can be reformulated in words by "the additive inverse of $(-x)$ is $x$". So we want to show that $(-x)+x=x+(-x)=0$. But this is true by the definition of $-x$.

**Another easy exercise:** By the same idea, prove that $(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$ for $a\neq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

The opposite (or additive inverse) of the element $a$ is $b$ such that
$$
a+b=0=b+a
$$
Such an element $b$ is unique and is denoted by $-a$.

Since the equalities are true it with $a=-x$ and $b=x$, you get that $x$ is the opposite element to $-x$, that is,
$$
-(-x)=x
$$

Answer (score 1):

We know the additive inverse axiom:
$$
-x + x = 0 \quad\text{for all}\quad x.
$$

Following Rudin's suggestion, we replace $x$ by $-x$ and get

$$
-(-x) + (-x) = 0.
$$
Both expressions are equal to zero, so we can set them equal to each other.

$$
x + (-x) = -(-x) + (-x).
$$

Now we note that for them to be equal $x$ must be equal to $-(-x)$, i.e.,
$-(-x)=x$ which was to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

We can start with the additive inverse
$$x+(-x)=0$$
We then plug $-x$ in for $x$ to get
$$(-x)+(-(-x))=0$$
Now we add these 2 values to $x$
$$(-x)+(-(-x))+x=0+x$$
Using commutative property on the left side and additive identity on the right, we get
$$x+(-x)+(-(-x))=x$$
We then can use additive inverse to get
$$0+(-(-x))=x$$
And finally, we use additive identity to get
$$-(-x)=x$$